# How to capture audio from microphone and save it in FLAC file format type in Java?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I need to make a simple app in java, that capture some audio from microphone, and save it in file, using FLAC. I found tutorial :
http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2105421/Java-Sound-Capturing-Microphone-Data-into-an-Audio-File.htm , 
but I need save file in flac audio, so I added jFLAC library, and I'm simply doing:

```
AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine), FlacFileFormatType.FLAC, new File("junk.flac"));
```

but I get an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not write audio file: file type not supported: FLAC
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.write(AudioSystem.java:1346)
at pl.com.stream.snippet.concurentmap_test.AudioRecorder02$CaptureThread.run(AudioRecorder02.java:211)
```

Is there any example or tutorial, that shows, how to save audio file in flac format in Java?

Answer (score 2):

From the [info. page on JavaSound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info):

### Service Provider Interface

The Java Sound API uses a Service Provider Interface to identify encoders & decoders for sound formats and sequence types. This way, adding support for a new format or type is as simple as providing a decoder and/or encoder for it, adding an SPI file to the manifest of the Jar it is in, then adding the Jar to the run-time class-path of the application.  ...

Further quote from that page:

### Java Sound Capabilities

The capabilities of the sampled sound API can be obtained using such methods as `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` ...

---

I think if you iterate the array returned by that method, you will find that FLAC is not listed.  The solution is to add a FLAC encoder using the SPI.